# ldap users unable to ssh to the server

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

I have configured ldap local server running centos 7, using this article: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html.

Now my LDAP server is running without any issue.
In my ldap server firewall is disabled. However, selinux is enabled.

Also, I migrate my local users to ldap db using migrationtools and it was also successful.

Also, I install and configure phpldapadmin and it was also successful. 
Then I have connected my another ldap server as client (I installed sssd, krb5-workstation, and use authconfig-tui to connect), just for authentication.

When I test my ldap connectivity (from clientserver) using

```
[root@ldapclient ~]# getent passwd user1

user1:*:1001:1001:user1:/home/user1:/bin/bash

[root@ldapclient ~]# id user1

uid=1001(user1) gid=1001 groups=1001

[root@ldapclient ~]# id testfromphpldapadmin

uid=1003(testfromphpldapadmin) gid=1010(ldapusers) groups=1010(ldapusers)
```

(testfromphpldapadmin - create from using phpldapadmin
user1 - user that migrate using migration tools)

according to the previous result, I was thinking that my ldap authentication just works without any issue

But when I tried to ssh using that ldap user accounts

```
login as: user1

user1@centclient's password:

Access denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for a successful login two things have to work:

1. Name service switch configured in file /etc/nsswitch.conf
2. PAM config as defined in various files in directoy /etc/pam.d

Since `getent` seems to return correct data your /etc/nsswitch.conf seems to be correct.

Then I'd check configuration in /etc/pam.d/common* whether it uses module *pam_sss.so*. And of course you should examine your logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't find any resolution at all. I will show you my /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/pam.d config file